# Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: ..., for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(...)]

Tags: jsf, hibernate, jpa

Estou com um problema muito simples utilizando JSF + JPA c/ Hibernate. Tenho duas classes: Mensagem e Comentario.. A classe Mensagem contém uma lista de Comentários. Mas ao tentar fazer esse relacionamento o erro abaixo acontece. Alguém pode ajudar? Grato!

Erro:

```
An Error Occurred:
[PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory~
```

Console:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: mensagem, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(comentarios)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 75 more
```

Comentario.java:

```
@Entity
public class Comentario {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;

    public Comentario(){}

    public Comentario(String descricao){ 
    this.descricao=descricao;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Comentario other = (Comentario) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Mensagem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mensagem")
public class Mensagem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cor;
    private List<Comentario> comentarios;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mensagem")
    public List<Comentario> getComentarios() {
        return comentarios;
    }

    public void setComentarios(List<Comentario> comentarios) {
        this.comentarios = comentarios;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public String getCor() {
        return this.cor;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Mensagem other = (Mensagem) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

MensagemBean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MensagemUI {
    private Mensagem mensagem;
    private Comentario comentario;
    public Comentario getComentario() {
        return comentario;
    }
    public void setComentario(Comentario comentario) {
        this.comentario = comentario;
    }
    public Mensagem getMensagem() {
        return mensagem;
    }
    private String novaMensagem = "";
    private String novoResumo = "";
    private String novaDescricao = "";
    public String getNovaDescricao() { return novaDescricao; }
    public void setNovaDescricao(String novaDescricao) { this.novaDescricao = novaDescricao; }
    public void setNovaMensagem(String novaMensagem){ this.novaMensagem = novaMensagem; }
    public String getNovaMensagem(){ return this.novaMensagem; }
    public void setNovoResumo(String novaCor){ this.novoResumo = novaCor; }
    public String getNovoResumo(){ return this.novoResumo; }
    public Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public MensagemUI() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void limpar(){
        mensagem = new Mensagem();
        comentario = new Comentario();
    }

    public void inserir () {
        MensagemModel model = new MensagemModel();
        model.inserir(this.novaMensagem, this.novoResumo);
        this.novaMensagem = "";
        this.novoResumo = "";
    }

    public List <Mensagem> getLista () {
        MensagemModel model = new MensagemModel();
        return model.getMensagens();
    }


    public List<Mensagem> getMensagem (Long id) {
        MensagemModel model = new MensagemModel();
        return model.getMensagem(id);
    }

    public void setMensagem(Mensagem mensagem) {
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
    }

    public Mensagem mensagem (){
        return this.mensagem;
    }


}
```

MensagemModel:

```
public class MensagemModel {
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory = null;

    public void inserir (String novaMensagem, String novaCor) {
        Mensagem f = new Mensagem();
        EntityManager em = MensagemModel.getEM();
        f.setNome(novaMensagem);
        f.setCor(novaCor);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(f);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Mensagem> getMensagens () {
        EntityManager em = MensagemModel.getEM();
        List <Mensagem> lista = (List <Mensagem>) em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM mensagem f").getResultList();
        em.close();
        return lista;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEM () {
        if (MensagemModel.factory == null)
            MensagemModel.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
        return MensagemModel.factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Mensagem> getMensagem(Long id) {
        EntityManager em = MensagemModel.getEM();
        List <Mensagem> lista = (List <Mensagem>) em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM mensagem f WHERE id=:id")
                .setParameter("id", id)

                .getResultList();
        em.close();
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi a tua anotação:  @OneToMany(mappedBy="mensagem"). O que você está querendo fazer?

Comment: A ideia é que uma Mensagem tenha vários Comentários. Portanto, estou tentando mapear a associação.